# Memory usage: List of list of strings versus list of strings

Tags: python, list, memory-management

I have a long list of strings, from which I generate a list of list of strings by splitting the strings like this:

```
import lorem
sentences = [lorem.text() for i in range(100000)]
split_sentences = [i.split() for i in sentences]
```

I noticed was that `split_sentences` takes up a lot of memory (almost 1GB) compared to `sentences`. I assume this is because of the overhead of the new lists, but the amount of extra memory taken surprises me.

Is this just how Python works, or is there a way to reduce memory usage? I need the lists, otherwise an alternative would be to use a generator.

Comment: how you calculating the size ? in my system it is taking `824464 bytes` ie 800KB

Comment: You can make split_sentences a generator comprehension

Comment: I agree with @prashantrana. On my system `sentences` and `split_sentences` have the same size. You can check it with, e.g., `sys.getsizeof`.

Comment: As I am aware, `sys.getsizeof` doesn't measure memory-usage accurately when it comes to lists. I am fairly sure the two objects do not have the same size, although `sys.getsizeof` says so

Comment: I am using sys.getsizeof()